# C Programming loop odd behavior

Tags: c, for-loop

I have a program that visits all the elements in an array both forwards and backward when STEP is set  = 1.
When I set STEP = 2, as you would expect, the 0th byte is visited, then two bytes skipped, then the 2nd byte visited, etc.
When I set STEP = 3, again, both forward and backward visitations are correct.
But When I set STEP = 4, it looks like the forward walk is correct, but the backward walk goes off by two.
(Maybe) interestingly, step = 5 is also broken, and STEP = 6 is once again synchronized.
What am I missing here?

```
#include <stdio.h>
typedef signed int int32_t;
#define STRIDE 1
void WalkForward()
{
    int32_t i;
    int format = 0;
    for (i = 128 - 1; i > 0; i -= STRIDE)
    {
        printf("[%3d], ",128 - i - 1);
        if (format++ > 10){format = 0;printf("\n");}
    }
    printf("\n\n");
}
void WalkBackward()
{
    int32_t i;
    int format = 0;
    for (i = 1; i < 128; i += STRIDE)
    {   
        printf("[%3d], ", 128 - i - 1 );
        if (format++ > 10) { format = 0; printf("\n"); }
    }
    printf("\n\n");
}
int main()
{
    LOOP:
    WalkForward();
    WalkBackward();
    goto LOOP;
}
```

Here are the data sample output. (Sorry for the lengthy examples, but I feel it's the best way to convey what's happening.

```
STEP=1 (okay)
[  0], [  1], [  2], [  3], [  4], [  5], [  6], [  7], [  8], [  9], [ 10], [ 11],
[ 12], [ 13], [ 14], [ 15], [ 16], [ 17], [ 18], [ 19], [ 20], [ 21], [ 22], [ 23],
[ 24], [ 25], [ 26], [ 27], [ 28], [ 29], [ 30], [ 31], [ 32], [ 33], [ 34], [ 35],
[ 36], [ 37], [ 38], [ 39], [ 40], [ 41], [ 42], [ 43], [ 44], [ 45], [ 46], [ 47],
[ 48], [ 49], [ 50], [ 51], [ 52], [ 53], [ 54], [ 55], [ 56], [ 57], [ 58], [ 59],
[ 60], [ 61], [ 62], [ 63], [ 64], [ 65], [ 66], [ 67], [ 68], [ 69], [ 70], [ 71],
[ 72], [ 73], [ 74], [ 75], [ 76], [ 77], [ 78], [ 79], [ 80], [ 81], [ 82], [ 83],
[ 84], [ 85], [ 86], [ 87], [ 88], [ 89], [ 90], [ 91], [ 92], [ 93], [ 94], [ 95],
[ 96], [ 97], [ 98], [ 99], [100], [101], [102], [103], [104], [105], [106], [107],
[108], [109], [110], [111], [112], [113], [114], [115], [116], [117], [118], [119],
[120], [121], [122], [123], [124], [125], [126],

[126], [125], [124], [123], [122], [121], [120], [119], [118], [117], [116], [115],
[114], [113], [112], [111], [110], [109], [108], [107], [106], [105], [104], [103],
[102], [101], [100], [ 99], [ 98], [ 97], [ 96], [ 95], [ 94], [ 93], [ 92], [ 91],
[ 90], [ 89], [ 88], [ 87], [ 86], [ 85], [ 84], [ 83], [ 82], [ 81], [ 80], [ 79],
[ 78], [ 77], [ 76], [ 75], [ 74], [ 73], [ 72], [ 71], [ 70], [ 69], [ 68], [ 67],
[ 66], [ 65], [ 64], [ 63], [ 62], [ 61], [ 60], [ 59], [ 58], [ 57], [ 56], [ 55],
[ 54], [ 53], [ 52], [ 51], [ 50], [ 49], [ 48], [ 47], [ 46], [ 45], [ 44], [ 43],
[ 42], [ 41], [ 40], [ 39], [ 38], [ 37], [ 36], [ 35], [ 34], [ 33], [ 32], [ 31],
[ 30], [ 29], [ 28], [ 27], [ 26], [ 25], [ 24], [ 23], [ 22], [ 21], [ 20], [ 19],
[ 18], [ 17], [ 16], [ 15], [ 14], [ 13], [ 12], [ 11], [ 10], [  9], [  8], [  7],
[  6], [  5], [  4], [  3], [  2], [  1], [  0],

STEP=2 (okay)
[  0], [  2], [  4], [  6], [  8], [ 10], [ 12], [ 14], [ 16], [ 18], [ 20], [ 22],
[ 24], [ 26], [ 28], [ 30], [ 32], [ 34], [ 36], [ 38], [ 40], [ 42], [ 44], [ 46],
[ 48], [ 50], [ 52], [ 54], [ 56], [ 58], [ 60], [ 62], [ 64], [ 66], [ 68], [ 70],
[ 72], [ 74], [ 76], [ 78], [ 80], [ 82], [ 84], [ 86], [ 88], [ 90], [ 92], [ 94],
[ 96], [ 98], [100], [102], [104], [106], [108], [110], [112], [114], [116], [118],
[120], [122], [124], [126],

[126], [124], [122], [120], [118], [116], [114], [112], [110], [108], [106], [104],
[102], [100], [ 98], [ 96], [ 94], [ 92], [ 90], [ 88], [ 86], [ 84], [ 82], [ 80],
[ 78], [ 76], [ 74], [ 72], [ 70], [ 68], [ 66], [ 64], [ 62], [ 60], [ 58], [ 56],
[ 54], [ 52], [ 50], [ 48], [ 46], [ 44], [ 42], [ 40], [ 38], [ 36], [ 34], [ 32],
[ 30], [ 28], [ 26], [ 24], [ 22], [ 20], [ 18], [ 16], [ 14], [ 12], [ 10], [  8],
[  6], [  4], [  2], [  0],

STEP=3 (okay)
[  0], [  3], [  6], [  9], [ 12], [ 15], [ 18], [ 21], [ 24], [ 27], [ 30], [ 33],
[ 36], [ 39], [ 42], [ 45], [ 48], [ 51], [ 54], [ 57], [ 60], [ 63], [ 66], [ 69],
[ 72], [ 75], [ 78], [ 81], [ 84], [ 87], [ 90], [ 93], [ 96], [ 99], [102], [105],
[108], [111], [114], [117], [120], [123], [126],

[126], [123], [120], [117], [114], [111], [108], [105], [102], [ 99], [ 96], [ 93],
[ 90], [ 87], [ 84], [ 81], [ 78], [ 75], [ 72], [ 69], [ 66], [ 63], [ 60], [ 57],
[ 54], [ 51], [ 48], [ 45], [ 42], [ 39], [ 36], [ 33], [ 30], [ 27], [ 24], [ 21],
[ 18], [ 15], [ 12], [  9], [  6], [  3], [  0],

STEP=4 (broken)
[  0], [  4], [  8], [ 12], [ 16], [ 20], [ 24], [ 28], [ 32], [ 36], [ 40], [ 44],
[ 48], [ 52], [ 56], [ 60], [ 64], [ 68], [ 72], [ 76], [ 80], [ 84], [ 88], [ 92],
[ 96], [100], [104], [108], [112], [116], [120], [124],

[126], [122], [118], [114], [110], [106], [102], [ 98], [ 94], [ 90], [ 86], [ 82],
[ 78], [ 74], [ 70], [ 66], [ 62], [ 58], [ 54], [ 50], [ 46], [ 42], [ 38], [ 34],
[ 30], [ 26], [ 22], [ 18], [ 14], [ 10], [  6], [  2],

STEP=5 (broken)
[  0], [  5], [ 10], [ 15], [ 20], [ 25], [ 30], [ 35], [ 40], [ 45], [ 50], [ 55],
[ 60], [ 65], [ 70], [ 75], [ 80], [ 85], [ 90], [ 95], [100], [105], [110], [115],
[120], [125],

[126], [121], [116], [111], [106], [101], [ 96], [ 91], [ 86], [ 81], [ 76], [ 71],
[ 66], [ 61], [ 56], [ 51], [ 46], [ 41], [ 36], [ 31], [ 26], [ 21], [ 16], [ 11],
[  6], [  1],

STEP=6 (back in sync)
[  0], [  6], [ 12], [ 18], [ 24], [ 30], [ 36], [ 42], [ 48], [ 54], [ 60], [ 66],
[ 72], [ 78], [ 84], [ 90], [ 96], [102], [108], [114], [120], [126],

[126], [120], [114], [108], [102], [ 96], [ 90], [ 84], [ 78], [ 72], [ 66], [ 60],
[ 54], [ 48], [ 42], [ 36], [ 30], [ 24], [ 18], [ 12], [  6], [  0],
```

Comment: In `WalkBackward`, the value in brackets will *always* start at 126 `(128 - i - 1` will always be 126 when i = 1). I suspect that's not what you meant to do..

Comment: `I set STEP = 4, it looks like the forward walk is correct, but the backward walk goes off by two. `   -    What do you mean by goes off by 2? you are starting from 126 and decrementing by 4... `126%4 != 0`

Comment: @Bob Jarvis Yes, you are correct. How do I appropriately offset the backward walk so that it works correctly given various STEP values?

Comment: I suggest playing around with `126 % STRIDE` and see what you can do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You make things much to complicated by counting down in the forward and counting up in the backward.

Just make it simple - forward counts up - backward counts down:

```
#include <stdio.h>
typedef signed int int32_t;
#define STRIDE 6
#define LIMIT 127
void WalkForward()
{
    int32_t i;
    int format = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < LIMIT; i += STRIDE)
    {
        printf("[%3d], ", i);
        if (format++ > 10){format = 0;printf("\n");}
    }
    printf("\n\n");
}
void WalkBackward()
{
    int32_t i = ((LIMIT-1)/STRIDE) * STRIDE;
    int format = 0;
    for (; i >= 0; i -= STRIDE)
    {   
        printf("[%3d], ", i);
        if (format++ > 10) { format = 0; printf("\n"); }
    }
    printf("\n\n");
}
int main()
{
    WalkForward();
    WalkBackward();
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, STEP=1 fails as it ends at 126 in the forward walk, but starts at 127 in the backward walk.

Comment: @Level42 ok - I guess I misunderstood what you wanted. Answer updated